# How to get image compression quality from IIOMetadata?

Tags: java, jpeg, javax.imageio, gimp, image-compression

When saving a new image with `ImageIO` generic `ImageWriteParam` supports explicit setting of `compressionQuality` parameter from range `0.0f` (high compression) to `1.0f` (high quality) regardless of image compression algorithm used (eg. png, jpeg, gif).

- Is there any way to read `compressionQuality` from an existing image?
- Is that `compressionQuality` write parameter just a hint to `ImageWriter` and is not stored anywhere in image's metadata? If that's true how image processing software (e.g. GIMP) manages to provide the following option in 'Save As' dialog?

[image: Image Save As Advanced Options]
[image: checkbox tooltip]

I managed to read `IIOMetadata` from `ImageInputStream` and iterate through its `metadataFormatNames` to print out image metadata in different XML formats (native and standard `javax_imageio_1.0`, usually). Although I couldn't find any indication of image's `compressionQuality` in there.

Comment: although some software and some image format *may* allow to store that information you typically cannot do what you want.  Take a jpeg saved as "80% quality" (whatever that means).  Now convert it to a PNG.  Now re-convert it to a jpeg saved as "80% quality".  Even if the file format saved the quality, you'd get what? 80%?  That would be totally wrong.  It's 80% of 80% (once again, whatever that "80%" means).  Also, for some format, the "compression quality" depends on the quality of the compressor.  One program's "80%" percent may be, for some formats, another program's "70%", etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that compressionQuality is stored with image meta data, this is processing parameter only.